# google-maps-react default zoom doesn't work with bounds prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

I came across this issue today where if i have bounds set on my map, the zoom prop doesn't work. Basically i have an object with bounds set to the following:

```
{ "south": -25.5469, "west": 65.45898, "north": 32.587894, "east": 31.3069 }
```

This basically negates my zoom prop. This is how I'm calling my component.

```
<Map google={google} initialCenter={avgCenter} zoom={10} bounds={bounds}>
```

If i have 1, 10 or 1000 as my zoom, it wont change but if I remove my bounds, it works. I think it's stuck to a 2 or 3 zoom by default. Anybody know a work around for this problem? I just want to change the default props, when my map renders I can actually zoom in and out with no problems.

The package I am using is the following [Google-Maps-React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react)

Comment: It looks like it is intended since using bounds will take the google.maps.LatLngBounds() object to adjust the center and zoom of the map as mentioned in the [google-maps-react docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#examples). You can just use a zoom level value that covers the area of your bounds.